# I don't want to login if I already login in node js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Everything is going great which I shared code but the problem is that when I log in the next time when I visit the website it shows me again the login form so I don't want this process repeatedly

I used there bcrypt,jwt token and cookies for user login

**This is my route where I define user register and login**

```
    router.post("/api/usersave", urlencodedParser, vUserController.createUser)
    router.post("/api/userlogin", urlencodedParser, vUserController.loginUser)
```

**This is my controller of user registration and login**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path")
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const hbs = require('hbs');
const router = express.Router()
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const cookieparser = require("cookie-parser")



exports.createUser=(req, res)=>{
    // console.log(req.body.itemname)
    const oldUser =  userModel.findOne({ username: req.body.username });

    if (oldUser) {
      return res.status(409).send("User Already Exist. Please Login");
    }
    const rsUsers = new userModel(req.body)
    rsUsers.save().then(() => {
        console.log('User: ' + req.body.username + ' Saved')
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log('User Saved Error..' + err)
    });
    res.render("home", {abc: req.body})  
    // res.send("User Created ... ")
    return true
}

exports.loginUser= async (req, res)=>{    
    // console.log(req.body.username)
    // console.log(password)
    var password = req.body.password
    const findUser = await userModel.findOne({username: req.body.username})
    // console.log(findUser.username)    
    if (!findUser){                             
            res.send("User ID Not Found")
        }
    else {
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, findUser.password, function(err, result) {
            if (!result){
                // console.log('User Login Failed')
                res.send("User Login Failed")
            }
            else{
                console.log('User Login Successfully')

                const vToken = findUser.generateJWTToken()  
                res.cookie("node1", vToken)

                // console.log(vToken)
                res.render("home", {abc: req.body})
            }                
        });
    }        
}
```

**This is my model of user registration and login**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path")
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")


const schema2 = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true},
    useremail: String,
    password: String,
    tokens: [{
        token: String
    }]
})

schema2.pre('save', async function(next){
    // var saltrange = bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    if(this.isModified("password")){
    var saltrange = 10
    this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, saltrange)
    next()
    }
})

schema2.methods.generateJWTToken = function(){
    try {
        var generatedtoken = jwt.sign({id: this._id}, "FULLSTACKWEBDEVELOPMENTMEANMERNBATCH")                
        // console.log(generatedtoken)
        this.tokens = this.tokens.concat({token: generatedtoken})
        this.save()       
        return generatedtoken    
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        return "false"
    }
}


const userModel = mongoose.model('userModel', schema2)
module.exports = userModel
enter code here
```

Comment: Just set a flag for each user to tell if the user is logged in or not if he is then reject the request or log out all the devices I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can control this login page rendering by checking you are valid login user or not. You can check this by a middleware function in your route file

```
const {isLoggedIn} = require("./middleware");
app.get("/login", isLoggedIn, (req, res)=>{
    res.render("login");
})

app.get("/reg", isLoggedIn, (req, res)=>{
    res.render("userRegister");
})

//For Logout from this session simply hit logout url
router.get('/logout', async (req, res) => {
    res.clearCookie('node1')
    res.redirect("/login");
});
```

where isLoggedIn is a middleware function which will check if you are an existing valid user or not

> middleware.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports.isLoggedIn = async(req,res, next)=>{
    try{
        const token = req.cookies ? req.cookies.node1 : null;
        const decoded = token ? jwt.verify(token, "FULLSTACKWEBDEVELOPMENTMEANMERNBATCH") : null
        if(decoded){
            return res.redirect('/home');
        }
        console.log(decoded);
        next();
    }catch(err){
        res.render("login");
    }
}
```

Hoping this may work in your case